# $\frac {\operatorname d\!y}{\operatorname d\!x}$ for $\sqrt{xy}=1$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

To find $\displaystyle \dfrac {\operatorname d\!y}{\operatorname d\!x}$ for $\sqrt{xy}= 1$:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt y}{2\sqrt x}+\dfrac{y'\sqrt x}{2\sqrt y}=0\\
\dfrac{y'\sqrt x}{2\sqrt y}=\dfrac{-\sqrt y}{2\sqrt x}\\
y'=\dfrac{-y}x$$

Is this correct? and can you show me how to get the same answer solving using $\ln$?

Comment: $$y''$$ should be $y'$ in the last line

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, edits made

Comment: This curve is the same as $xy=1$, no?

Comment: Yes, it even preserves _both_ branches of the hyperbola.

Comment: You should search logarithmic differentiation, it makes hard problems really simple

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{xy}=1\implies xy=1 \implies xy'+y=0 \implies y'=-\dfrac yx$.
So, yeah, this is true.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{xy}=1\implies \ln(\sqrt{xy})=\ln1$$

As $\displaystyle\ln y^m=m\ln y$ where both logarithm is defined unlike $\displaystyle\ln1=\ln(-1)^2=2\ln(-1)$
$$\implies \frac12\ln(xy)=0$$

As $\displaystyle\ln ab=\ln a+\ln b$ where both logarithm is defined unlike $\displaystyle\ln6=\ln (-1)(-6)=\ln(-1)+\ln(-6)$
$$\implies\ln |x|+\ln |y|=0$$

Differentiating we get
$$\frac{d(\ln|x|)}{dx}+\frac{d(\ln|y|)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln 1)}{dx}$$

$$\implies\frac1x+\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Comment: Formally it should be $\ln|x|,\ln|y|$.

Comment: @AlexR., agreed

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why not differentiate right away: we'll have immediately $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{xy}}(y+xy')=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I preferred chain rule to product rule

Comment: @Downvoter, Wish I know the mistake here.

Answer (score -1):

$$\ln \sqrt {xy} = \ln 1$$
$$\frac{\ln{x}+\ln{y}}{2}=0$$
$$\ln y=-\ln x$$
$$\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\!x} \ln y= - \dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d\!x}\ln x $$
$$\dfrac{\operatorname d \ln y }{\operatorname d\!y} \dfrac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname d\!x}  =-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\dfrac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname d\!x}  =-\frac{y}{x}$$